# How to compare instances of HMAccessory

Tags: ios9, homekit, hmaccessory

Since iOS9 the `identifier` property of `HMAccessory` has beed depreciated. Is there another way to compare two different instances of HMAccessory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new way to determine the HMAccessory in iOS 9 is by using the

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
@NSCopying public var uniqueIdentifier: NSUUID { get }
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Is there a reason why this property is not mentioned in the online docs?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. As @Maria mentioned, from iOS9 onwards, you have the NSUUID property 'uniqueIdentifier':

```
@property(readonly, copy, nonatomic) NSUUID *uniqueIdentifier NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);
```

Also, you can utilize the serialNumber characteristicType to compare HMAccessories, however, keep in mind: you should check for accessories' 'reachability' and 'blocked' status. If the accessories are unreachable or is blocked, then you may not be able to read serial number.

Lastly, I've included a utility code snippet in Objective C (want Swift? just ask, or better yet, use it as an exercise ;)):

/**
  @discussion: Returns empty string if accessory is unreachable.
  Cannot fetch the actual serial number in unreachable state.*
 */

**[Please cite if you are pasting this]**

```
+ (NSString *)getSerialNumberFromHMAccessory:(HMAccessory *)accessory {
    if (!accessory || !accessory.reachable || accessory.isBlocked) {
        return @"";
    }

    for (HMService *service in accessory.services) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@", @"characteristicType", HMCharacteristicTypeSerialNumber];
        NSArray *result = [service.characteristics filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

        if (result && [result count] > 0 && [result[0] isKindOfClass:[HMCharacteristic class]]) {
            HMCharacteristic *serialNumChar = (HMCharacteristic *)result[0];
            NSString *serialNum = [serialNumChar valueForKey:@"value"];
            if (serialNum && [serialNum length] > 0) {
                //DDLogInfo(@"Found serial number: %@ for accessory named \"%@\"", serialNum, accessory.name);
                return serialNum;
            }
        }
    }

    return @"";
}
```

Comment: your answer may did not help @Christian R but it made my day.
I was looking for a way to retrieve mac address after homekit install !

Answer (score -1):

Alright came up with one solution. There is a `HMCharaceteristic` `HMCharaceteristicTypeSerialNumber`. Made an extension to `HMAccessory`:

```
extension HMAccessory {
 var serialNumber: String? {
  get {
   for service in services {
    for characteristic in service.characteristics {
     if characteristic.characteristicType == HMCharacteristicTypeSerialNumber {
      return characteristic.value as? String
     }
    }
   }
   return nil
  }
 }
}
```

Can now compare:

```
accessory1.serialNumber == accessory2.serialNumber
```

Any other solutions?

Comment: 1. Check for accessory 'reachability' and 'blocked' status.
2. serialNumber is of type NSString. Use NSString comparability check: "isEqualToString" and not " == " is you are so inclined to do it this way.